# Change coordinate systems in for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have quantity (say $V$) represented in (x,y,z) coordinate, each has complex (phase and amplitude) value, i.e., $$ V = |V_x| \exp(j \gamma_{x}) a_x +  |V_y| ~\exp(j \gamma_{y}) a_y +  |V_z| ~\exp(j \gamma_{z}) a_z$$

where $|V_x|$ and $\gamma_{x}$ are the amplitude and phase of $V$ in the unit direction $a_x$ (i.e., in x), same for $a_y$ and $a_z$. I need to convert that quantity to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$.
I know how to do that if we have only real components, but not sure  how to proceed when we have real and imaginary for each component.

In particular, if $\gamma = 0$ for all directions, then we have 
$$V_r = \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) V_x  + \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) V_y  + \cos(\theta) V_z $$
$$V_\theta = -\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) V_x  + \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) V_y  - \sin(\theta) V_z $$
$$V_\phi = -\sin(\phi) V_x  + \cos(\phi) V_y $$

Comment: Note that $V_r=V\cdot a_r$ etc., so you need the dot products of two sets of unit vectors to complete the calculation.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the comment, could you please elaborate? is't that similar to what we have in the first equation above (for $V_r$)? where $a_r . a_x = sin(\theta) cos(\phi)$ etc? how would that address the complex value?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) for the dot products. As for complex numbers, $V_x=|V_x|\exp(j\gamma_x)$ etc. simplifies the original formula for $V$.